# Change DHCP range and tcpip connections

Tags: ip, dhcp-server, tcpip, dnsmasq

I want to change the dynamic range of my DHCP server for a network e.g. it is at the moment `from 192.168.0.2 to 192.168.0.100` I want to move it `from 192.168.0.101 to 192.168.0.200` but I don't want to break the connections/sessions. If I have dnsmasq in place which is providing the DHCP/DNS, would this change in the IP range (DHCP) break the connections/session when the client's IP is changed after the lease-time is expired and the client tries to get a new IP (which will be from the new range).

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if a machine's IP address changes then any existing open connections will be closed.

So at the end of the lease time, the machine will ask the DHCP server if it can keep it's current IP address, as the range has changed it will be denied and issued a new address from the new pool.

The best way to do this is if the machines are only used for a specific period of time, e.g. "office hours" you could first reduce the lease time down to say an hour.

Then wait until 90 mins after the end of the work day and make the pool range change, that way there would be minimal/no on going sessions that would be dropped.

Comment: If the connections are established using the Hostnames, then would the machine which initialized the connection/session not query the DNS again for the Hostname once the old IP isn't responding ?

Comment: That would still result in the connection being dropped and restarted, you can not just change IP addresses in and existing connection